# Cannot import _has_surrogates from email.utils for requests

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

When I try to use requests for APIs in python I get the error.  This is the same for multiple APIs

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 39, in <module>
from email.generator import BytesGenerator
File 

"/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/email/generator.py", line 16, in <module>
from email.utils import _has_surrogates
ImportError: cannot import name '_has_surrogates' from 'email.utils' (/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/email/utils.py)
```

I am able to import `email.utils` and `requests` but when I try `email.utils._has_surrogates` I get the message

```
No module named 'email.utils._has_surrogates'; 'email.utils' is not a package
```

I opened the file with nano and the function is there.